# WordPress Custom Post Types - Pretty Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I was wondering if anyone knew how to achieve 'pretty' permalinks with WordPress 3.0 custom post types?

Even with the permalink structure set to `/%category%/%postname%/` - when you add a post to a custom post type, the default URL is `/?post_type=event&p=20` for example.

I understand they've re-written how WP deals with custom post types now but is there any way possible to make custom posts take the URL (for example) `/events/post-name` ?

You could do this easily with More Fields / WordPress 2.9 so it seems annoying if you can't replicate this with WP 3.0.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Hey I have the same problem but cant solve.How your's solved pls? @mattberridge